# yii2 katik-v the datetimepicker does not appear

Tags: php, yii2

I install via composer this plugin. When i click in the buttons or set focus in the input field the dateTimePiker doesn't appear. I use the code example the kartik-v and is the follow:

```
use kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker;

echo 'Start Date/Time';
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
'name' => 'datetime_10',
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select operating time ...'],
'convertFormat' => true,
'pluginOptions' => [
'format' => 'd-M-Y g:i A',
'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
'todayHighlight' => true
]
]);
```

But when i click in the button to open calender he do not appear. i'm using this scripts:

```
<!-- jqGrid -->

    <!-- jQuery UI 1.10.3 -->
    <script src="/vsoftservice/web/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <!--<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="/vsoftservice/web/js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/vsoftservice/web/js/moment-with-locales.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/vsoftservice/web/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/vsoftservice/web/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
 <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="/vsoftservice/web/js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/vsoftservice/web/js/jquery-ui-dateTimePiker-Pt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can't use jquery version heither because the phpgrid doesn't work. Exists more dependecies or other way to install?

Comment: Is the widget loaded correctly? If you have more than one datetime field you must set an unique id for each <input> field. Have you tried another browser,have you cleared your browser-cache and the ../web/asset folder?

Comment: I have tried in chrome and firefox browser.  the withget load correctely appears the input text and two buttons. One to open calender and the other to clear but none works. And I tried clear web/assets an still don't work. I think he needs more js files to load